# Migrate from Tomcat 6.0 to jboss-5.1

Tags: web-applications, tomcat6, jboss5.x, migrate

I have used Apache Tomcat 6.0.32 all along developing my web application(jsp-struts-hibernate)
Now i have a requirement to make it work in JBOSS AS 5.1.

While deploying the XYZ.war file in JBOSS deploy folder, I am getting errors like:

org.jboss.profileservice.spi.NoSuchDeploymentException: Failed to find deployment in file: XYZ.war

15:19:33,287 WARN  [AbstractManagedObjectPopulator] Cannot create String name from non-Simple property: ManagedProperty{JNDIName,JNDIName,metaType=SimpleMetaType:java.lang.String}, value=null
15:20:17,322 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Parse: name=vfszip:/C:/AppServer/Experiments/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/XYZ.war/ state=Not Installed mode=Manual requiredState=Parse
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error creating managed object for vfszip:/C:/AppServer/Experiments/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/XYZ.war/

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfszip:/C:/AppServer/Experiments/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/XYZ.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Can anyone please help me explain what i need to do to make it work, since i am very new to JBOSS?

Thanks and Regards,
rishi

Comment: Please do proper allignment in your post. Highlight the errors properly in-order to have quick and nice replies. However, looking in to your error `java.net.ConnectException` I guess your XYZ.war is trying to connect somewhere while starting and its getting failed for the same. Check that one